# Change color based on recursion depth Python Turtle

Tags: python, recursion, colors, modulo, turtle-graphics

I have a coding problem I'm having trouble with. I am learning recursion and so far having a pretty good time with it. We've starting with basic turtle drawings using the python turtle graphics module. I've got the picture code down, but I'm also supposed to change the color of the turtle's pen based on depth. My professor only briefly touched on mod (%) to achieve this, but I have no idea where to begin and was hoping for some assistance. Thanks in advance. I can't add pics because my rep isn't high enough, but basically if you run the code it draws "S" figures. The first "S" should be green, second two red, third three green, etc. Thanks again. Here's the code:

```
from turtle import *

def drawzig2(depth,size):
    if depth == 0:
        pass
    elif depth:
        left(90)
        fd(size/2)
        right(90)
        fd(size)
        left(45)
        drawzig2(depth-1,size/2)
        right(45)
        fd(-size)
        left(90)
        fd(-size)
        right(90)
        fd(-size)
        left(45)
        drawzig2(depth-1,size/2)
        right(45)
        fd(size)
        left(90)
        fd(size/2)
        right(90)

drawzig2(4,100)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
from turtle import *

colors = ['green', 'red']

def drawzig2(depth,size):

    if depth == 0:
        pass
    elif depth:
        pencolor(colors[depth % len(colors)])
        left(90)
        fd(size/2)
        right(90)
        fd(size)
        left(45)
        drawzig2(depth-1,size/2)
        right(45)
        fd(-size)
        left(90)
        fd(-size)
        right(90)
        fd(-size)
        left(45)
        drawzig2(depth-1,size/2)
        right(45)
        fd(size)
        left(90)
        fd(size/2)
        right(90)

drawzig2(4,100)
```

Comment: Hmm, that changed the colors. But the whole thing ended up red at the end. I'll have to play with it. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, the solution by @xfx sets and then unintentionally unsets the color as it doesn't handle the color correctly with respect to recursion.  Here's a small modification that keeps track of the current color on entry to the routine (it could also be computed) and then restores it on exit.  This way, you don't have to worry about what your recursive calls do to the color, they should leave it as they found it:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

colors = ['green', 'red']

def drawzig2(turtle, depth, size):

    if depth == 0:
        return

    color = turtle.pencolor()

    turtle.pencolor(colors[depth % len(colors)])

    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.fd(size / 2)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.fd(size)
    turtle.left(45)

    drawzig2(turtle, depth - 1, size / 2)

    turtle.right(45)
    turtle.bk(size)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.bk(size)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.bk(size)
    turtle.left(45)

    drawzig2(turtle, depth - 1, size / 2)

    turtle.right(45)
    turtle.fd(size)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.fd(size / 2)
    turtle.right(90)

    turtle.pencolor(color)

yertle = Turtle()

drawzig2(yertle, 4, 100)

screen = Screen()

screen.exitonclick()
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]